# Spring data : @Transactional and propogation

Tags: java, spring, orm, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I have the following code:

```
public void method1(String id){
  Object object = repository.findOne(id);
  object.setState("running");
  repository.save(object);
  try{
    object2.method2(object); //This method takes 2 hours to complete
    object.setState("complete");
  }catch(Exception e){
    object.setState("failed");
  }
  repository.save(object);
}
```

So, I change the state to "running" before calling a method that takes hours to execute. My object is a JPA `Entity`(with lazily loded collections) and `method2()` tries to load all the linked `entities`.

Now, in `method2`, I am getting

> could not initialize proxy - no Session

error because it is outside of transaction (expected behavior). To prevent this, there are two solutions:

- Annotate `method1` with `@Transactional`. This would solve it, but then, the `state` won't be reflected to other transactions until the method execution finishes.
- Change the `fetch mode` in Entity config and make it `Eager`. This would also solve it but I don't want `eager` fetching every time.

Is there any other way by which I can make it work?

Comment: Sorry but how much data do you have, two hours to load the linked entities sounds insane. Is it not possible to manipulate these entities in the database without loading them.

Comment: `method2` doesn't perform any update or delete operation actually. All it does is `read`, so maybe a simpler option would be to convert the entity to Dto and send it to `method2`.

Comment: Why do you load the data if you are not manipulating it. If you are manipulating something else based on the entities, then it may be possible to select the data you need rather than all the linked entities. Typically long load times like this suggest that misuse of Eager loading, or some other conceptual mistake. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

**Option 1**

**1)** Create a service method for status changing like following:

```
@Transactional( propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void changeStatusInNewTransaction(String id, String status){
  Object object = repository.findOne(id);
  object.setState(status);
  repository.save(object);
}
```

**2)** Change the original method as follows:

```
@Autowired
Service service;

@Transactional
public void method1(String id){
  service.changeStatusInNewTransaction(id, "running");
  Object object = repository.findOne(id);
  try{
    object2.method2(object); //This method takes 2 hours to complete
    object.setState("complete");
  }catch(Exception e){
    object.setState("failed");
  }
  repository.save(object);
}
```

Thanks to this set-up, everything can be run under one @Transactional method, but when the state is to be changed to 'running' then :

- The current transaction would be suspended
- New one would be created
- State would be changed and transaction commited
- Parent transaction would continue and you can process with your big operation not having a problem that other users will wont see the status change for 2 hours..

**Option 2**

**1)** Create a service method for status changing like following:

```
@Transactional
public void changeStatusInNewTransaction(String id, String status){
  Object object = repository.findOne(id);
  object.setState(status);
  repository.save(object);
}
```

**2)** Create transactional method just for long processing

```
@Transactional
public void performLongProcessing(String id){
    Object object = repository.findOne(id);
    object2.method2(object); //This method takes 2 hours to complete
    object.setState("complete");
    repository.save(objects;
}
```

**3)** Mark the main method to run without transaction:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public void method1(String id){
  service.changeStatusInNewTransaction(id, "running");

  try{
    service.performLongProcessing(id);
  }catch(Exception e){
    service.changeStatusInNewTransaction(id, "failed");
  }

}
```

Comment: Interesting. I have tried this but unfortunately it doesn't work. This is what the javadoc says `Actual transaction suspension will not work out-of-the-box on all transaction managers`, I need to check whether my transaction manager supports this.

Comment: Yes and your database has to support this kind of manipulation also

Comment: another idea just popped into my head.

Answer (score 1):

Having a transaction around a method that executes for several hours, seems like a design mistake, so `method1()` should not have @Transactional! When you start a transaction, you need a connection and this connection will be allocated from you connection pool for the entire duration, which greatly limits scalability (and pisses of your DBA).

> could not initialize proxy - no Session

You get this error because (without @Transactional on method1) your entity is detached after `repository.save()` has been called, and you can't load the lazy collections. A quick solution for this is to inject an EntityManager into object2 and call `EntityManager.refresh()` inside `method2()` this does not require a transaction, as you are only reading data.

There is no reason to use any sort of Transaction propagation to solve this issue.

Comment: Great point regarding keeping the transaction open for a long time. I don't really write anything in `method2` maybe I should try and pass the required fields (or convert it to dto) to `method2` instead of passing the actual entity.